# Auto Mapper Null Reference

Tags: automapper

I have an issue with auto mapper which throws a Null reference exception.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<People, PeopleDto>()
      .ForMember(d => d.Country, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o.Address.Country))
```

The problem is when Address is null and trying to get map Address.Country

Answer (score 5):

```
Mapper.CreateMap() 
    .ForMember(d => d.Country, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(
            o => (o.Address != null) ? o.Address.Country : "ADDRESS NOT SPECIFIED"
        )
    )
```